# Deploying Laravel to Heroku - problems with Jeffrey Way's Generators

Tags: heroku, laravel, push

So, I'm trying do deploy my Laravel project to Heroku. 
In my Vendor folder I have Jeffrey Way's Generators installed [/Vendor/Way]. And it seems like Heroku doesn't have it. I get the following whet I run `git push heroku master`

```
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 88, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (73/73), done.
Writing objects: 100% (88/88), 34.47 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 88 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> PHP app detected
-----> No runtime requirements in composer.json, defaulting to PHP 5.6.1.
-----> Installing system packages...
       - PHP 5.6.1
       - Apache 2.4.10
       - Nginx 1.6.0
-----> Installing PHP extensions...
       - zend-opcache (automatic; bundled, using 'ext-zend-opcache.ini')
-----> Installing dependencies...
       Composer version 73e9db5d9952d52a46ecbc20a269a8c5f9c5b011 2014-10-07 15:03:19
       Loading composer repositories with package information
       Installing dependencies from lock file
         - Installing symfony/translation (v2.5.5)
           Downloading: 100%         

         - Installing symfony/security-core (v2.5.5)
           Downloading: 100%         

         - Installing symfony/routing (v2.5.5)
           Downloading: 100%         

         - Installing symfony/process (v2.5.5)
           Downloading: 100%         

         - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v2.5.5)
           Downloading: 100%         

         - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v2.5.5)
           Downloading: 100%         

         - Installing symfony/debug (v2.5.5)
           Downloading: 100%         

         - Installing psr/log (1.0.0)
           Downloading: 100%         

         - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v2.5.5)
           Downloading: 100%         

         - Installing symfony/finder (v2.5.5)
           Downloading: 100%         

         - Installing symfony/dom-crawler (v2.5.5)
           Downloading: 100%         

         - Installing symfony/css-selector (v2.5.5)
           Downloading: 100%         

         - Installing symfony/console (v2.5.5)
           Downloading: 100%         

         - Installing symfony/browser-kit (v2.5.5)
           Downloading: 100%         

         - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.3.0)
           Downloading: 100%         

         - Installing stack/builder (v1.0.2)
           Downloading: 100%         

         - Installing predis/predis (v0.8.7)
           Downloading: 100%         

         - Installing phpseclib/phpseclib (0.3.8)
           Downloading: 100%         

         - Installing patchwork/utf8 (v1.1.25)
           Downloading: 100%         

         - Installing nesbot/carbon (1.13.0)
           Downloading: 100%         

         - Installing monolog/monolog (1.11.0)
           Downloading: 100%         

         - Installing nikic/php-parser (v0.9.5)
           Downloading: 100%         

         - Installing jeremeamia/superclosure (1.0.1)
           Downloading: 100%         

         - Installing ircmaxell/password-compat (1.0.3)
           Downloading: 100%         

         - Installing filp/whoops (1.1.2)
           Downloading: 100%         

         - Installing d11wtq/boris (v1.0.8)
           Downloading: 100%         

         - Installing symfony/filesystem (v2.5.5)
           Downloading: 100%         

         - Installing classpreloader/classpreloader (1.0.2)
           Downloading: 100%         

         - Installing laravel/framework (v4.2.11)
           Downloading: 100%         

       Generating optimized autoload files
       PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider' not found in /tmp/build_5ed58964-00a1-4095-976d-3975a31d73d8/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 157
       {"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'Way\\Generators\\GeneratorsServiceProvider' not found","file":"\/tmp\/build_5ed58964-00a1-4095-976d-3975a31d73d8\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/ProviderRepository.php","line":157}}Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error



  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider' not found in /tmp/build_5ed58964-00a1-4095-976d-3975a31d73d8/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 157  




install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [packages1] ... [packagesN]



 !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app

To git@heroku.com:tranquil-shore-5073.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:tranquil-shore-1111.git'
```

Why does it happens? How can I solve it?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok, I've figured it myself. It was a problem with my installation of these generators: I didn't use environments. Next comment is the guide to do it:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is my guide how to do it in Homestead.

---

1. Open terminal and do `$ vagrant ssh`

---

2. Change directory to your project [ex: `$ cd Code/webdev.local`]

---

3. Run `$ composer require way/generators --dev` [you can actually skip this step]

---

4. Update your project's composer.json "way/generators" to "dev-master" or "2.*" or "~3.0" - depending on your larval version [ex:

```
"require-dev": {
        "way/generators": "dev-master"
    }
```

]

---

5.Run `$composer update`

---

6. Navigate to your project and to app/config/local/app.php (if you don't have local folder - create it and then create app.php which starts like app.php) and set there `'providers'=>array('Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider'),`

---

7. Run `php artisan` to check the commands

Worked just fine for me!